# Как получить текст из QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qlineedit

Мне необходимо достать из `QLineEdit` текст и узнать его длину.

Пробовала вызывать `len(QLineEdit)`, но выдаёт ошибку, подскажите как сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнать длину `lineEdit`:

```
len(self.lineEdit.text())
```

Динамический это выглядит так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.lineEdit  = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.my_slot_function)
        
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)

    def my_slot_function(self, text): 
        self.label.setText(f'Длина строки: {len(text)}')
#        print(len(self.lineEdit.text()))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое